# screen brightness suddenly dimmed and now won't go above 50%

Tags: screen, brightness

I was just working on my computer doing nothing particularly interesting and my brightness suddenly dimmed and won't go back up above 50%. I can control the slider and I tried manually adjusting with `echo x | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` but anything above 5000 or the halfway point on the slider just doesn't get any brighter. Restarting doesn't do anything either. It could be a hardware issue but since I'm not dual booting I can't think of a meaningful way to test that, has anyone had this problem?

Comment: I am assuming this is a laptop?  There is probably a key combination to adjust the display brightness.

Comment: @Nmath yes there is a key combination which does work to control the brightness but not above 50%

Comment: Are you running on full battery?